# Want to present the delete button on right-to-left swipe in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        //[theSimpsons removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *time = [[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"TIME"];
        NSString *date= [[arrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"DATE"];
        DBManager *dbm = [[DBManager alloc] init];
        [dbm initiallzeDatabase];
        [dbm deleteItemAtIndexPath:time :date];

        //arrayList = [dbm getParkResults];
        //[parkTableView reloadData];

        [arrayList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

I have used the above code in my app. The editing part works fine, but the thing is, the delete button appears only when we swipe from left-to-right on a cell. Now i have a menu that opens on left-to-right swipe like Facebook. So how can i make sure that the delete button appears when the user swipes from right-to-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work. Put this code in `awakeFromNib` or `init`:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDelete = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeDelete:)];
[swipeDelete setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[yourTableView addGestureRecognizer:swipeDelete];
```

then in `handleSwipeDelete` organize your cell and show delete button. You will probably need to handle cell state and change it on swipeLeft/swipeRight.

Comment: I am giving this a try. When you say show Delete button, can we show the default delete button programmatically? If yes then how? Thanks :)

Comment: You might try to set table cell type to `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`when swipe left. Or create subclass of `UITableViewCell` and draw that cell instead of default one for that row.

Answer (score 6):

Please dont set the delegate to `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`

Write this in `viewDidLoad` or where you have initiated your `UITableView`

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(callYourMethod:)];
 swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
 [self.tblView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

**No need to write anything in the below method.**

```
- (void)callYourMethod:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Manohar. I got the answer by combining yours and @Gossamer's idea. Thanks both of you. You people saved me a lot of work. :)

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to customize the behaviour of UITableViewCell, I have never noticed that Apple has supplied the behaviour after swiping right to left....

Answer (score 1):

You can got it by using `two Methods of UITableVie.`

```
// This only needs to be implemented if you are going to be returning NO
// for some items. By default, all items are editable.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
     //When you remove a cell of your tableview, you also has to remove your array object at index x
    }    
}
```

After removing the object. You have to reload the `UITableView`.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

For More Information [Read This OfficialDocumentaion.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes thanks @iPatel. But as i said. the gesture could not be read coz am sliding in the menu at the same event. So this does not work. But thanks anyways. :)